# QED integral is zero in dimensional regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

Why is this integral zero in dimensional regularization?
$$
\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{(k^2)^n}.
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If $n\neq D/2$ then OP's integral is dimensionful (i.e. it has non-zero mass dimension $D-2n\neq 0$ in [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)), but it doesn't depend on any dimensionful parameters, so the only possible consistent answer of the regularization is zero.
2. If $n=D/2$ then OP's integral is logarithmically divergent, and in fact non-zero in [dimensional regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization).

Comment: Notes for later: Replace mass dimension with inverse length dimension.

Answer (score 2):

See around (8.33) of [Regularisation](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/08.pdf).
This is known as Veltman’s formula.
See also [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377966/help-understanding-loops-with-negative-superficial-degree-of-divergence) and [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136424/massless-integrals-in-dim-reg).

$$
\int d^n k \frac{1}{k^a} =  \lim_{m^2 \to 0}  \int d^n k \frac{1}{\left( k^2 - m^2 \right)^{a/2}} \propto \lim_{m^2 \to 0} m^{n-a}
$$

So integral is zero for $n>a$.

Comment: In addition, it is worth mentioning that dim. reg. insensitive to odd divergences, therefore it is possible to hide divergence and obtain zero answer